# refresh content of Activity or add refresh button

Tags: java, android, refresh

As I can refresh the content of an activity?, for example, I have a menu and a button send me an application content that displays information online, but to go back and return again, the information is not updated.

This is my Activity.

```
public class Bovalpo extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bovalpo);

    Button buttonExit = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.cerrar);
    buttonExit.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    );


    TextView myListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    try {
        myListView.setText(getPage());
        if(getPage().contains("Abierto")){
            myListView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        }else{
            myListView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

private String getPage() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=1").openConnection();
    con.connect();

    if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        return inputStreamToString(con.getInputStream());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}


private String inputStreamToString(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append("Mercado: " + line + "\n");
    }

    bufferedReader.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}



public void lanzar(View view){
 Intent i = new Intent(this, xml7009.class);
 startActivity(i);
}


public void lanzar3(View view){
 Intent i = new Intent(this, tabla7009.class);
 startActivity(i);
} 

public void lanzar4(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, xml6503.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void  onClick(View arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      finish();
    }
```

}

Comment: Note that doing IO on the UI thread (as you do in `onCreate()` when calling `getPage()`) may cause Android to force-close your application. Check out [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) for how to do IO in a separate thread. This will also make your UI more responsive. The same applies to any of the other lifecycle methods like `onStart()`, `onResume()`, etc. as well, don't do IO in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your code here

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

       // make your work to data bind


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that fetches your data and sets list view color should be put in `onResume()` instead of `onCreate` if you want it to run each time your Activity is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can put your update code in the [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method of the activity. OnResume() method will be called when ever you return from the other activity.
But onResume() method is often called when your activity is resume for example. If you open and dismiss the dialog then your activity will be Resume. SO if you are calling some network call in onResume then it will consume the process and Network speed.

The alternate solution is use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method to receive the result from the next activity and bases of the activity result you can call your web API or any work. You can get the result of the next activity in [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method. 
But before using the startActivityForResult method ensure that the next activity will set the result by calling [setResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your data every time you came to activity, you need to set your updated values in onResume

like below

```
@Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

                 try {
                      myListView.setText(getPage());
                      if(getPage().contains("Abierto")){
                       myListView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                      }else{
                       myListView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                      }
                      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `onResume()` is a better choice than `onStart()` for updating an activity every time the users returns to it according to the [Android Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: but when to push a button and return to where the button, there is the activity in the background?

Comment: ya, i thought it's too often. But it's correct onResume is better choice than onStart.